# About Django's widget design principles

Tags: python, django, widget

This is a question I've from time ago, as I just don't understand why was this decission headed that way.

When we render a widget (e.g., 'cause of using a form), its render functions has a `name` arg. Why, if a HTML tag name is an attr, cannot be specified as part of the `attrs` dict passed to that function? Should make more sense to use `name` only when you no specify an attr name.

For understanding, if I set an attrs `{"name": "no_one_knows[]"}`, when I render the widget its name should be `"no_one_knows[]"`, not the one passed by arg. That way I could have a HTML tag that can be parsed directly as a list (`getlist(..)`) in the server side (for example).

Comment: Ok, my `getlist(..)` example isn't valid, as Django parses it without need of `[]` in the name. But the idea is the same, be able to override the name.

Comment: What do you mean by rendering a widget "manually"?

Comment: Calling `widget.render(..)`, I'll edit, isn't so clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A widget makes no sense in the absence of a field. The field is responsible for accepting the input and validating it; so it is the field that has to determine the name attribute, otherwise it would have no way of knowing what value to use in the data.

Butu you should never need to render the widget directly by calling its `render` method. Again, that is the job of the field.

Comment: It's not about rendering the widget directly (strong reasons I need for it). But your answer clears my thoughts.